# Virtual Machine Allocation in Cloud Analyst Simulator

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine

I am using Cloud Analyst Simulator for performing my simulations. Can any one tell me that when any task is assigned to Virtual Machine then how cloud analyst came to know that if the task assigned to that machine is done or not ?

When will this machine be marked as free again ?

Comment: Welcome! Is this a question about code, or just how to submit simulations to Cloud Analyst by hand, and tell if they have finished? If you are trying to submit get status of simulations using code, then please post your code.

Comment: No i just want to know that on what basis the cloud simulator marked as free ..

Comment: Is it doing this on time basis ?   Means if any VM is assigned any  task then after a specific time the machine will be considered as free .. isn't it ?